# How to synchronise SwiftUI View and initializer?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI class that receives data as an object-array (swipeStackThemes) and a part of the data should be inserted in another array (indicesThemes). the input-array contains up to 100 elements, but i want to view to load only 5 at a point. I want to do this, because the data is supposed to be shown in a ZStack and i implemented a lazy loading function for a ZStack. However, when i print the transformed data in the console, its empty.

I am new to Swift and it seems to me that the view is loaded before the initializer has completed.

Here's my Code:

```
struct SwipeView: View {
    
    @State var swipeStackThemes: [ThemedlistStock]?
    
    @State private var indicesThemes: [ThemedlistStock] = []
    
    let max: Int
    let block = 3
    
    init(data: [ThemedlistStock]) {
        self.swipeStackThemes = data
        self.max = data.count
        
            var i = 0
            while i < block {
                self.indicesThemes.append(data[i])
                i += 1
            }
        print("----indicesThemes Count------")
        print(indicesThemes.count) // always returns zero
    }

var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack(alignment: .top){
                
                ForEach(indicesThemes, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text(index.name) // View is empty
                }
             }
        }
}}
```

I checked that the data is availiable and it works fine if i skip the transformation to another array

Comment: The `@State` property wrapper doesn't update right away. It's not really clear what you're trying to do here, since you're using `@State`, but nothing is mutable outside of the init. Maybe just don't use `@State`?

Comment: snipped a bit of the code there. indeed, @State is only necessary for indicesThemes

Comment: Please include a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to view 5 elements out of the array try this:

```swift
struct SwipeView: View {
    
    @State var swipeStackThemes: [ThemedlistStock]

    let block = 5 // Number of viewd elements 
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack(alignment: .top){
                
                ForEach(swipeStackThemes.dropLast( swipeStackThemes.count - block), id: \.self) { index in
                    Text(index.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to work with a second array.

```swift
struct SwipeView: View {
    
    @State var swipeStackThemes: [ThemedlistStock]

    @State private var indicesThemes: [ThemedlistStock] = []
    
    let block = 5
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack(alignment: .top){
                
                ForEach(indicesThemes, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text(index.name)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            let count = swipeStackThemes.count
            indicesThemes = swipeStackThemes.dropLast(count - block)
        }
    }
}
```